# How to populate a matrix using for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, rotation

C is a 2 by 360 matrix that forms outline of a unit circle. C = [v1|v2|v3... v360] where v1 is e rotated by 1◦, v2 is e rotated by 2◦ etc. R is a given rotation matrix. e is a column vector [1 0]

I initialized the matrix by

```
>> C=zeros(2,360);
```

I don't know how use the for loop to populate the entries of matrix C

```
>> for c = 1:360
C = (R^c)*e;
end
```

And then the following is supposed to plot the circle.

```
>> plot(C(1,:), C(2,:))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set each column at each rotation, so you will need to set C(:,c) at each rotation. ie

```
for c = 1:360
    C(:,c) = (R^c) * c;
end
```

However, you can do the whole thing without a for loop. (MATLAB likes avoiding for loops).

Since

```
t = 2*pi/360;
R = [cos(t) -sin(t); sin(t) cos(t)];
```

we have that

```
R*e = [cos(t); sin(t)];
```

So we're looking for

```
C = [cos(t) cos(2*t) ... cos(360*t);
     sin(t) sin(2*t) ... sin(360*t)];
```

ie

```
C = [cos(t * (1:360)); sin(t * (1:360))];
```